# Fragment to Fragment Communication NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity that holds two fragments (Frag1 and Frag2)

What I'm trying to do is: everytime I click the button in Frag1, "The button was clicked" string should be displayed in the EditText in Frag2.

I'm using a ViewPager, so I don't have Fragment ID's.
I set a communicator interface and a Fragment Tag.
But I don't know if I've set my Fragment Tag Correctly.

Here's my code:

**Communicator interface**

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void respond(String data);

}
```

**Frag1**

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener { 

Button button1;
Communicator comm;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    comm = (Communicator)getActivity();

    button1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    comm.respond("The button was clicked");     


}

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator {

ViewPager viewPager = null; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);    
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {  

    public MyAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            fragment = new Frag1();
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            fragment = new Frag2();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }   
}

@Override
public void respond(String data) {

    Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frag2, "Hello").commit();

    Frag2 frag = (Frag2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Hello");
    frag.changeText(data);
}

}
```

**Frag2**

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment { 

    EditText edittext1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        edittext1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    }

    public void changeText(String data) {
        edittext1.setText(data);
    }

}
```

**error in LogCat after clicking button in Frag1**

```
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at lmf.test5.MainActivity.respond(MainActivity.java:59)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at lmf.test5.Frag1.onClick(Frag1.java:35)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-10 21:22:09.210: E/AndroidRuntime(9760):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you move the `comm = (Communicator) getActivity()` line to `onAttach()`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should wait for pending transactions to be executed in `respond(String data)`. But you can execute:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

before:

```
Frag2 frag = (Frag2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Hello");
frag.changeText(data);
```

and I suppose it should be fine

---

btw, you should rewrite your `void respond(String data)`, in the same way as it is in example from google guides: [Deliver a Message to a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver). The problem is that when adding new fragment, you should pass data using setArguments, but when fragment already exists then you can call method on it. This way you wont need executePendingTransactions().

Comment: Won't this be a tight coupling of the fragments?

Comment: Probably yes, this method it suggested by google actually: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @marcin_j - what's the better method to use and why?